# How to show not modal window top of child windows of outlook

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook-addin

I am developing Outlook vsto-plugin. I need to show not modal (popup) window which will be top of all child outlook windows (such as new-mail, mail-read, etc).   I have implemented this scenario by setting the main window of outlook as owner to my popup. It approach works almost correct except 1 thing: at the momemt of shown popup the main window is actiavated to, so if user was reading mail fom separate maximaized window at that moment he/she faced the main outlook window instead mail. It's not acceptable. But how I can fix this behavioral. I need to show my popup over all child windows. And additional: if outlook is minimized - popup should minimized too. Thanks

```
var explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer()                    
IntPtr windowOutlook = WinApi.GetOutlookWindowHandler(explorer);

var interop = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
interop.Owner = windowOutlook;
```

Comment: Please post more code - we can't diagnose the problem from the 4 lines you've posted so far.